# I will see my friend to the airport. Why the progressive seems to be not possible?

Tags: grammar, progressive-aspect

I assume this is correct:

> I will see my friend to the aiport.

But for this, I cannot see a single hit on Google:

> I'm seeing my friend to the airport.

I'm using the progressive to express that this is a plan, something that is for sure going to happen (at least according to my plan) and I am familiar with this kind of usage. However, I have not seen in used with this verb and in this context. Is there something special about this sentence in particular?

Comment: Have you read the question and answers about [the present progressive representing a future event](/questions/389585)?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [The reasoning behind the present progressive representing a future event](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/389585/the-reasoning-behind-the-present-progressive-representing-a-future-event)

Comment: @AndrewLeach I did, I am asking whether it is correct in this particular case...

Comment: But the other question answers that. It is. "I can't come tomorrow. I'm washing my hair" is exactly equivalent to "I can't come tomorrow. I'm seeing my friend to the airport" or "I'm seeing my friend off at the airport" or "I'm taking my friend to the airport". Or is your question really about using *seeing* to mean "accompanying"?

Comment: @AndrewLeach Yes, I mean "to see sb somewhere" as in "to accompany sb somewhere". E.g. "I will see her to the train station".

Comment: So like sense 5 in [Oxford/Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/see)?

Comment: @AndrewLeach Yes, in this sense.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Well, I've found three sentences below on Google, in which "seeing someone to something" is used and confirmed that the authors who wrote them are all native speakers of English.

1.Jennifer is packing the last of her camera equipment, and SJP is seeing me to the door.

2.We need to be at the transport van at six a.m. My mom insists on seeing me to the van.

3.“Seeing me to the hotel won't be necessary, Sheriff.”