# Why is this sentence 'her train is leaving tomorrow at 10AM' correct?

Tags: grammar, tenses, future

The word 'tomorrow' implies that the sentence should be in the future sentence. Wouldn't the correct sentences be 'her train will leave tomorrow at 10AM' or 'her train will be leaving tomorrow at 10AM'?

How can the present tense be used for something that happens in the future?

Comment: When things are preplanned, it's par for the course to use the progressive tense to talk about future events.

Comment: Present tense is common for scheduled events.

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["The train will leave" vs. "is going to leave" vs. "leaves" vs. "is leaving"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/59292/the-train-will-leave-vs-is-going-to-leave-vs-leaves-vs-is-leaving)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [The reasoning behind the present progressive representing a future event](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/389585/the-reasoning-behind-the-present-progressive-representing-a-future-event)

Comment: Interestingly, the closing sentence of your question uses the present tense “happens” to refer to the future.

Answer (score 3):

When we use the present continuous to talk about a plan in the future, it is called **Future Arrangement Present Continuous** in English grammar. It is used to emphasis that you are certain that something will happen, to the point that you can talk about it as if it's already happening in front of your eyes.

[BBC English explanation](https://www.bbc.co.uk/worldservice/learningenglish/flatmates/episode73/languagepoint.shtml)

Both *"will be leaving"* and *"is leaving"* are correct, but the latter implies more certainty, and is less formal. The Present continuous for future arrangements is usually used in ***spoken*** English.